# html hidden input type - base 64 value

Tags: html

Suppose you are looking at a website. You look at the source of the website (for example the [Gibson SG page](http://www.gibson.com/Products/Electric-Guitars/2016/USA/SG-Standard-P-90/High-Performance.aspx)). You see a wall of base64 text inside of the value of an `<input>` tag.

[image]

What is this massive base 64 value inside a `<input type="hidden" ...` tag? What are they trying to accomplish?

I'm trying to ask this question as a web developer. Why would someone put a large block of base 64 text inside an input html tag?

Comment: For starters, have you tried calling `atob` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, when you want to deliver large amounts of data, such as an image for example, they will encode the image or data into Base64 text. It does make the file larger, yet it makes the file readable on more devices. Why? Because normally you will not want to deliver data or images in its raw format. This is because some media were made to stream text, not raw data.

To avoid delivering data using its raw format, they encode it in the Base64 format. Most do not use other Bases because the characters within them are not common within all computers, and Base64 can be read on most computers.